# Atualizar página quando usuário estiver ausente e não houver vídeos na página

Tags: php, html

Preciso atualizar a página do meu site quando o usuário ficar inativo por 15 minutos e quando não houver vídeos incorporados na mesma.

se o usuário ficar inativo em uma página do site por 15 minutos a página deverá ser atualizada, mas não pode atualizar se a página possuir algum vídeo do youtube incorporado.

Sempre que houver um vídeo incorporado ele usará este código:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*VIDEOID*" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Sabemos se há video caso haja ou não algum iframe na página?

Comment: @Miguei sim, sempre que houver iframe será algum vídeo, caso tenha sido essa a pergunta :)

Comment: Foi sim, coloquei uma maneira em baixo, mas é com javascript/jquery, só com html/php não dá para fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só com php/html não dá para fazer isso, mas aqui está um exemplo de fazer com javascript/jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    if($('iframe').length < 1) // caso não exista iframe vamos incrementar o contador (idleTime) de 1 em 1 minuto
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minutos

    // resetamos o contador caso sejam detetados estes eventos
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 14) { // 15 minutes
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
```

Exemplo adapatado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Caso não fosse preciso detetar alguma atividade na página bastaria no `head` do teu html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
```

Em que content é o número de segundos antes do refresh

Comment: desculpe a ignorância, estou começando a trabalhar com isso agora, mas fiz o seguinte http://i.imgur.com/8m6DJde.png e parece que não atualiza a página. Tentei modificar para atualizar a cada 10 segundos para ver se funciona, mas nada acontece. Fiz algo errado?

Comment: Vou ver se algo se passa, confesso que não testei @talnun. É importante estares a importar o jquery, mas eu vou testar rápido

Comment: @talnun acabei de testar, funcionou tudo ok, muda para `setInterval(timerIncrement, 100);` para testar, não te esqueças que estamos a trabalhar com milisegundos

Comment: Repara aqui a funcionar @talnun: https://jsfiddle.net/eeuqq7ux/

Comment: realmente faltava importar o jquery, funcionou como esperado. Gratidão.